# Failed to launch DevTools: TimeoutException after 0:00:10.000000: Future not completed

Tags: flutter

The flutter tools aren't launching when I press the button on Android Studio, and I also get a warning when I use `flutter run`.

I've tried `flutter clean`, but this still happens on both the terminal and Android Studio flutter plugin.

[image]

`flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale
    en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restrat...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting my computer fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing routes from State provider to Core Navigator works for me.

Have a look at the detailed answer here.

[StackOverflow answer in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76768264/12522385)