# Flutter iOS crashing when removed from recent stack and opened Again - Not detecting in Crashlytics or Sentry

Tags: flutter, crash, crashlytics, startup, sentry

[image]

Flutter doctor - v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.10.1 on channel stable at
      /Users/poojabhardwaj/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d3d8effc68 (7 days ago), 2023-05-16 17:59:05 -0700
    • Engine revision b4fb11214d
    • Dart version 3.0.1
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/poojabhardwaj/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
    • VS Code at /Users/poojabhardwaj/Downloads/BrandSek Data/Visual Studio
      Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 14 Pro (mobile) • 871DFC69-8FE7-4C95-B9AD-A2D737B8298A • ios
      • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)        • macos                                •
      darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               •
      web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.126

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

We have integrated Crashlytics and also Sentry to capture the trace but nothing is working and its happening on iOS 16.5, 16.4.1

We have integrated Crashlytics and also Sentry to capture the trace but nothing is working and its happening on iOS 16.5, 16.4.1

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve the issue? I am getting the same problem for physical devices upgraded to iOS 16.5.

Comment: @BradG I am still not able to find the solution for this issue. I have also raised the issue with the Flutter team but due to lack of logs and explanation the ticket is closed. But I found the reason why this is happening. 
[application<com.wecopytrade.app>:822] Executing termination request: <FBSProcessTerminationRequest: 0x2818935c0; label: "graceful termination failed"; exceptionCode: "Watchdog Violation (0x8BADF00D)"; reportType: CrashLog; explanation: "[application<com.wecopytrade.app>:822] failed to terminate gracefully after 5.0s">
Please see the Mac Console app for the actual reason.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in my app as you've described.

I changed my Route navigation from **Getx To Navigator** and it works for me.

Don't use the route of state management, but **use the core Navigator** in the Flutter app.

[Have a look at the code I changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5qts.png)